# DeepLinks not opening correct activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have 2 activities - MainActivity and DeepLinkActivity. MainActivity generates a link. When I click on the DeepLink from an sms, I expect the DeepLinkActivity to open however the MainActivity always opens.

Manifest file is as follows:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DeepLinkActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDialogActivity">

        <!-- [START deep_link_filter] -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:host="blessd.mobi" android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:host="blessd.mobi" android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- [END deep_link_filter] -->
    </activity>
```

Snippet of both activities

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_referral);


        //long
        String link = "http://www.blessd.mobi";
        DynamicLink m = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                .setLink(Uri.parse(link))....
```

DeepLinkActivity

```
public class DeepLinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = DeepLinkActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deep_link_activity);
        Log.d(TAG,"Deep Activity" );

        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                    }...
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the link you are clicking on?

Comment: the link is blessd.page.link. That seems to be the issue, the link that i had in the intent was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest activity, you must have filter:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="yourlinkhost.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="yourlinkhost.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />

            </intent-filter>
```

And it should handle your links. Maby your links have wrong host scheme - I had such problem when my link had wrong host. But the solution you have - seems good and the same I had worked well for me.

Comment: thanks the link was indeed incorrect it should be the link created in firebase console - dynamic links

Answer (score 0):

You must add the additional data on your intent filters.

```
           <data
            android:host=""
            android:path=""
            android:scheme="" />
```

And you must have set that data while you were creating share intent.

```
builder.scheme(getString(R.string.config_scheme)) // "http"
            .authority("your url") // your host
            .appendPath(getString(R.string.path)) // "your path"
            .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, data)
```